# How to write a simple error interceptor?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

Here's my first attempt of a catcher interceptor on Pedestal:

```
(definterceptorfn catcher []
   (interceptor
   :error (fn [context error]
           {:status 500 
            :body (->> error .toString (hash-map :error) json/write-str)
            :headers {"Content-type" "application/json"}})))
```

As I could test, by adding **(/ 1 0)** to my code, the function does get called, but the client gets an empty response with status 200, instead of the response in the map. I wonder why it is so.

There is nothing fancy in my routes variable:

```
(defroutes routes
  [[["/api"
     ^:interceptors [(body-params/body-params) (catcher) bootstrap/html-body]
     ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tim Ewald explained](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/issues/152#issuecomment-21479940), I was returning a response map when a context was needed.

Fixed with

```
(definterceptorfn catcher []
   (interceptor
   :error (fn [context error]
           (assoc context :response
            {:status 500 
             :body (->> error .toString (hash-map :error) json/write-str)
             :headers {"Content-type" "application/json"}}))))
```